# how to figure out the object is packaged/namespaced in describe result

Tags: apex, describesobject

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm

I checked the above and try to find out the custom object is linked with any package.

It is getting all custom objects including managed package objects. How can I avoid(filter) managed package objects.

Is there any way to find out the name is not linked with any package ?

salesVision__Key__c  - installed package object

Answer (score 2):

Its not available that easily and I didn't find anything in describe result.

Salesforce doesn't allow us to add a double underscore to API name, but appends __c at end. Only way for an object to have a double underscore is if from a managed package, because salesforce prepends `NameSpace__` to object API name.

By this information, we know that a custom object API with single `__` is custom object from org, and with two `__`'s is from package.

Let the action begin, I have used [countMatches](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_countMatches) string function to identify ic object is from package or not. Apex psuedo code is as follows:

```
for(Schema.SObjectType fieldDescribe: Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values()) {
    String apiName = fieldDescribe.getDescribe().getName();
    if(fieldDescribe.getDescribe().isCustom()) {
        if(apiName.countMatches('__') > 1) {
            // its a custom object from package
            System.debug('Packaged object name: ' + apiName);
        } else {
            // its a custom object from package
            System.debug('Non-Packaged/Orgs object name: ' + apiName);
        }
    } else {
        // its a standard object
            System.debug('Standard object name: ' + apiName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I got this regex pattern from forum and figure out the way.

```
//Code start
Integer objectCount = 0; 
Integer customSettingCount = 0;
//Regex to filter managed package objects
Pattern regEx = Pattern.compile('^\\w*?__\\B\\w*__');
for ( Schema.SObjectType o : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values() )
{
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objResult = o.getDescribe();
    Matcher filter = regEx.matcher(objResult.getLocalName().toLowerCase());

    if(objResult.isCustom() && filter.find() == false)
    {           
        objectCount++;        
    }
    if(objResult.isCustomSetting() && filter.find() == false)
    {              
        customSettingCount++;           
    }
}
System.debug('Total custom object :'+ objectCount);
System.debug('Total custom Setting :'+ customSettingCount);

//Code End
```

Comment: why some one down voted ? explain ? or give better solution ?